# Would it be possible to implement ROS with a robotic teaching arm?

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For something like these examples:

[http://www.amazon.com/Robotic-Degrees-Freedom-Electronix-Express/dp/B00CLEONBK/ref=sr_1_2?s=toys-and-games&ie=UTF8&qid=1400094756&sr=1-2&keywords=robot+teaching+arm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CLEONBK)

http://www.adafruit.com/products/548?gclid=CPH49pqPrL4CFcVffgodpkcAfw

Would it be possible to implement ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164766/would-it-be-possible-to-implement-ros-with-a-robotic-teaching-arm?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Implementing ROS" with an arm sounds a bit misleading I think. ROS is already implemented (but of course evolving over time). You can certainly use a multitude of ROS tools with hobbyist hardware though. If you create a URDF model, you could easily visualize a robot model in [rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) or even plan motions using [MoveIt!](http://moveit.ros.org/). Some caveats apply of course, for example if your arm doesn´t have joint angle sensing, you could provide fake joint angle measurements by just taking the desired values you sent to the system (which might or might not work very well).
You´d likely also have to do some low level interfacing with a Microcontroller, but [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino), [ros_arduino_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge), [rosc](http://wiki.ros.org/rosc) and others could help with that.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1